# How to split these records into individual new ones?

Tags: sqlite, sql-insert, recursive-query, substr, db-browser-sqlite

I want to search if a string exists in column2 (`site_id`) then put that string in a new table with the value of its before column in that row. The table has only 2 columns and the `site_id` column may have many 5-word strings that I want.

I want to get all of the the specific site id's. For example: E7089 or E7459 (I need all of them and the first word is random like E or T or etc and the four digits are variable).

The first row is with one `ticket_id` and many `site_id`s. I only need site ids like:g1231 or g1236 and not the addresses in parentheses:

| ticket_id | site_id |
| --- | --- |
| sss-bb-12312312-12312 | g1231(afsdgf-sdgsdgdg), g1236(sdfsdgsdg), g3212(asdfas-dfsd), b2311(asdasd), b3213(asdfsdf) |

And make it like this:

| ticket_id | site_id |
| --- | --- |
| sss-bb-12312312-12312 | g1231 |
| sss-bb-12312312-12312 | g3211 |
| sss-bb-12312312-12312 | g1236 |
| sss-bb-12312312-12312 | b2311 |
| sss-bb-12312312-12312 | b3213 |

I can find the 5-word site id's with regexp `[A-Z]\d{1,4}`, but I can't extract and insert them into a new row. My code :

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test2;

CREATE TABLE if NOT EXISTS test2 
(
    Ticket_id varchar,
    site_id varchar
);

INSERT INTO test2 
    SELECT ticket_id, site_id 
    FROM TEST 
    WHERE site_id regexp '[A-Z]\d{1,4}';
```

This will find the `site_id`'s and insert rows that match. I don't want that. How to convert the first one to the second?

Current db :

| column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- |
| ticket1 | many site ids |
| ticket2 | many site ids |

I want it to be :

| column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- |
| ticket1 | id |
| ticket1 | id |
| ticket1 | id |
| ticket1 | id |
| ticket2 | id |
| ticket2 | id |
| ticket2 | id |

- The tickets do not need any change except getting copied into new rows with their assigned `site_id`.
- There are multiple `site_id`s for each ticket that need to be separated to new rows.
- It needs to be done in SQLite db browser (unfortunately no Python).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a recursive CTE to split the `site_id` column of the table `test1` and SUBSTR() function to take the first 5 chars to insert in the table `test2`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT ticket_id, '' site_id, site_id || ',' s 
    FROM test1
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT ticket_id,
           SUBSTR(s, 0, INSTR(s, ',')),
           SUBSTR(s, INSTR(s, ',') + 1)
    FROM cte 
    WHERE s <> ''
) 
INSERT INTO test2 (ticket_id, site_id) 
SELECT ticket_id, SUBSTR(TRIM(site_id), 1, 5) 
FROM cte
WHERE site_id <> '';
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=95a61df0a6ff46495c63e10c0356226b).